# Excluding/including traffic based on URI in Google Analytics profile filters

Tags: filter, google-analytics

How do you exclude traffic from a certain directory (and everything under it) from an entire Google Analytics profile?

Example:
www.thesite.com - should be tracked
www.thesite.com/directory/ - should not be tracked, along with anything below it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lots of experimenting I found a way to do this. I hope this can help someone else later.

Under Profile >> Filters there are predefined filters and custom filters. The predefined exclude would not work for me no matter how I wrote it, but I didn't manage to get the custom filter to work.

I used:
Filter type: Custom filter - Exclude
Filter Field: Request URL
Filter Pattern: (^/directory/)

This works for both excludes, and to "include only", i.e. to create a profile that ONLY tracks things going to www.thesite.com/directory/